# Set pdf file password in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, itext, password-protection

I am using this approach to generate pdf file with `pdfDocument` library. Here is my code wrapped in `MainActivity.java` file

declared variable

```
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
Button generatePDFbtn;

// declaring width and height
// for our PDF file.
int pageHeight = 1120;
int pagewidth = 792;

// creating a bitmap variable
// for storing our images
Bitmap bmp, scaledbmp;
```

override oncreate function

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;

    generatePDFbtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnGeneratePDF);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.test.png, options);
    scaledbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 140, 140, false);

    // below code is used for
    // checking our permissions.
    if (checkPermission()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        requestPermission();
    }

    generatePDFbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // calling method to
            // generate our PDF file.
            try {
                generatePDF();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

generatePDF function

```
private void generatePDF() throws FileNotFoundException {
      PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      Paint title = new Paint();
      PdfDocument.PageInfo mypageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pagewidth, pageHeight, 1).create();

      PdfDocument.Page myPage = pdfDocument.startPage(mypageInfo);

      Canvas canvas = myPage.getCanvas();

      canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbmp, 56, 40, paint);

      title.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.NORMAL));
      title.setTextSize(15);
      title.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_200));

      canvas.drawText("A portal for IT professionals.", 209, 100, title);
      canvas.drawText("Geeks for Geeks", 209, 80, title);

      title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
      title.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.purple_200));
      title.setTextSize(15);

      title.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
      canvas.drawText("This is sample document which we have created.", 396, 560, title);

      pdfDocument.finishPage(myPage);

      File directoryFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

      File saveFile = new File(directoryFile, "test.pdf");

      try {
          pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(saveFile));
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "PDF file generated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      pdfDocument.close();
  }
```

I googled anywhere to find how to set password for pdf file and it seems `pdfDocument` library does not provide a function to do so. Is there any library or way to set password when pdf file is created in android?

**NOTE:** I tried using itext core 7 with following version `7.2.0` but the pdf file which generated by code below is corrupted. I tried to downgrade the pdf library to worked version which `5.5.3.1`, but that version is no longer exist anymore. Anyway, here is the way I am implementing generate pdf using itext core 7

```
String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
        File file = new File(pdfPath, "test.pdf");

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Technology").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)
                .setFontSize(15);
        document.add(paragraph);
        document.close();
```

Comment: @KJ I attempt to make pdf readable instead of writable. Did you suggest me to replace pdf writer to pdf reader? I simply want when the user download the pdf file, it has password on it. It is not pointless if you develop digital banking apps such as downloading transaction history and open it as pdf file. Imagine if someone lend me their mobile phone and I can open that downloaded pdf file in download directory. That is my purpose to protect user privacy. so NO, it is not pointless.

Comment: Yes, pdf is designed to be both readable and writable but you can set them to readonly right? well I know in android we can protect the file by setting them to privacy and it is done by user (not programmatically). But once again, it is good opinion about user restriction and privacy. And there is nothing wrong to try protect user file which downloaded by apps we made. For example, in iOS they can set the password to pdf file. https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/secure-documents-with-pspdfkit-for-ios/

Comment: Yes, I will put it into account the feature you mentioned whereas the user can choose whether the file they access it is kept the default as unencrypted or not. From your point of view, it will prevent from making any difficulty for the user access their own file. Thanks for the really good input. Yes, I've been searching about iText version 7.1 it has option to encrypt and decrypt the pdf file.

Comment: @KJ Would you like to answer my question and providing us the example implementation of iText version 7.1 to encrypt and decrypt the pdf file? it would help me and others a lot. Since the question actually to secure pdf file.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks anyway! your observation sounds cool and I agree because it will give full access to the user as the user privacy purposed to (reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy). I actually still in early step to learn user privacy & restriction. File access is one of them. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved using itext core 7.1^ as K J mentioned above. For those of you who want to know how the implementation or the code, here is how:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ... 
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.13' // add this library
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**PermissionChecker**

```
public class PermissionsChecker {

    /**
     * Permission List
     */
    public static String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSION = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    /**
     * Context
     */
    private final Context context;

    public PermissionsChecker(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean lacksPermissions(String... permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (lacksPermission(permission)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean lacksPermission(String permission) {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED;
    }
}
```

**PermissionActivity**

```
public class PermissionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int PERMISSIONS_GRANTED = 0;
    public static final int PERMISSIONS_DENIED = 1;

    public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    private static final String EXTRA_PERMISSIONS = "com.koops.sales.EXTRA_PERMISSIONS";
    private static final String PACKAGE_URL_SCHEME = "package:";

    private PermissionsChecker checker;
    private boolean requiresCheck;

    public static void startActivityForResult(@NonNull Activity activity, int requestCode, String... permissions) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PermissionsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSIONS, permissions);
        ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(activity, intent, requestCode, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent() == null || !getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSIONS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This Activity needs to be launched using the static startActivityForResult() method.");
        }
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_permissions);

        checker = new PermissionsChecker(this);
        requiresCheck = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (requiresCheck) {
            String[] permissions = getPermissions();

            if (checker.lacksPermissions(permissions)) {
                requestPermissions(permissions);
            } else {
                allPermissionsGranted();
            }
        } else {
            requiresCheck = true;
        }
    }

    private String[] getPermissions() {
        return getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(EXTRA_PERMISSIONS);
    }

    private void requestPermissions(@NonNull String... permissions) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void allPermissionsGranted() {
        setResult(PERMISSIONS_GRANTED);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE && hasAllPermissionsGranted(grantResults)) {
            requiresCheck = true;
            allPermissionsGranted();
        } else {
            requiresCheck = false;
            showMissingPermissionDialog();
        }
    }

    private boolean hasAllPermissionsGranted(@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
            if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void showMissingPermissionDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PermissionsActivity.this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.string_permission_help);
        dialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.string_permission_help_text);
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.string_permission_quit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                setResult(PERMISSIONS_DENIED);
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.string_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startAppSettings();
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.show();
    }

    private void startAppSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(PACKAGE_URL_SCHEME + getPackageName()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
import com.myapplication.R;
import com.myapplication.PermissionsActivity;
import com.myapplication.PermissionsChecker;
....

import static com.myapplication.permission.PermissionsActivity.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE;
import static com.myapplication.PermissionsChecker.REQUIRED_PERMISSION;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   PermissionChecker checker;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...

      String dest = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/test.pdf";
      checker = new PermissionsChecker(this);
      if (checker.lacksPermissions(REQUIRED_PERMISSION)) {
         PermissionsActivity.startActivityForResult(MainActivity.this, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, REQUIRED_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        generatePDF(dest);
    }
  }

  private void generatePDF(String dest) {
      WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
      writerProperties.setStandardEncryption("1234".getBytes(), "1234".getBytes(), EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
      PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(dest), writerProperties);
      PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
      Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4, true);

   // Init pdf property for writing
      Color mColorAccent = new DeviceRgb(153, 204, 255);
      Color mColorBlack = new DeviceRgb(0, 0, 0);
      float mHeadingFontSize = 20.0f;
      float mValueFontSize = 26.0f;

      PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont("assets/fonts/brandon_medium.otf", "UTF-8", true);

      Text mOrderIdValueChunk = new Text("#Example pdf password").setFont(font).setFontSize(mValueFontSize).setFontColor(mColorBlack);
      Paragraph mOrderIdValueParagraph = new Paragraph(mOrderIdValueChunk);
      document.add(mOrderIdValueParagraph);
       
      document.close();
      Toast.makeText(mContext, "Pdf successfully created with password :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
       } catch (ActivityNotFoundException eActivity) {
           Toast.makeText(mContext, "No application found to open this file.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == PermissionsActivity.PERMISSIONS_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Permission Granted to Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Permission not granted, Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

  // to open pdf file
  private void openPDF(String dest) {
      new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +
                        "/" + dest));
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
                intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intent);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.d("TAG", "run: Error");
              }
          }
      }, 1000);
  }
}
```

**Conclusion**

The main part to set password for pdf file is using WriterProperties as second parameter of PdfWriter object.

```
WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
writerProperties.setStandardEncryption("1234".getBytes(), "1234".getBytes(), EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING, EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(dest), writerProperties);
```